# Search and replace string and also put a counter in replacements

Tags: regex, perl, string

I have a bunch of files containing the exact same log message. One of them happens but as messages are identical I don't known which one. What I want to do is append a number after all these messages to distinguish them.

Now usually when I have a bunch search and replace to perform I just write a quick perl one-liner like:

```
perl -pi -e 's/searched/replacement/g' *.c
```

But how can I insert a counter in replacement ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `e` regex modifier to append a running counter value to your replacement as:

```
perl -pi -e 's/searched/"replacement".++$i/ge' *.c
```

Demo:

```
$ cat file
hi foo
hey foo
bye foo

$ perl -p -e 's/foo/"bar".++$i/ge' file
hi bar1
hey bar2
bye bar3
```

Comment: Almost the same as mine :) - you'll actually want the extra quotes though, if the replacement text is anything more complex than "bar", or else perl will try to evaluate that too :-)

Answer (score 4):

This does the trick for me:

```
perl -pi -e 's/one/"replacement".$counter++/ge' *.c
```

Answer (score 2):

If your counter needs initialization, put your initialization code in a BEGIN block (so it executes only once, at the start).

```
perl -p -e 'BEGIN {$ctr =99;} s/searched/replaced$ctr/; ++$ctr;' file
```

Answer (score 1):

*EDIT: OOPS This may only be helpful if your main project is in perl, too.*

This is probably somewhat offtopic, but what about adding automagic location detection to the log messages? Like,

```
sub whereami {
    my $shout = shift;
    my @stack = caller(1);
    print LOG "$stack[1]:$stack[2]: $shout\n";
}
```

(see perldoc caller)

Or even better, `use Log::Log4perl qw/:easy/;` -- it might be an overkill, but it's worth a try.